# How to find minimum possible height of tree?

Tags: data-structures, tree, height, children, minimum

The fan-out of a node in a tree is defined to be the number of children the node has.  The fan-out of a tree is defined to be the maximum fan-out of any node in the tree.  Assume tree T has n nodes and a fan-out f > 1.  What is the minimum possible height of T?

I have no idea how to begin this problem.  I solved the first part which is to find the maximum number of nodes that can be T in terms of height h and fan-out f > 1.  I got (f^(h+1) -1)/(f-1).  I'm thinking you can use this to solve for the question above.  Can someone please point me in the correct direction?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would approach this problem by turning it around and trying to find the maximum number of nodes you can pack in a tree with a given height and fan-out `T_max(h,f)`. This way, every other tree `T(h,f)` is guaranteed to have as much, or less nodes than `T_max(h,f)`. Therefore, if you find such `T_max(h,f)`, that

```
total_nodes( T_max(h,f) ) > n > total_nodes( T_max(h-1,f))
```

`h` will be guaranteed to be the minimum height of a tree with `n` nodes and `f` fan-out.

In order to find such a tree, you need to maximize the number of nodes in every layer of a tree. In other words, *every* node of such a tree needs to have fan-out of `f`, no less. Therefore you start inserting nodes in a tree, one level at a time. After a layer is full, you start adding another layer. After `n` nodes are inserted in such a tree, you stop and check the height of the tree. This will be the minimal height you are looking for.

Or, you can do a calculation instead:

```
nodes_in_level(1) = 1
nodes_in_level(2) = f
nodes_in_level(3) = f * f
...
nodes_in_level(x) = f ^ (x - 1)
```

This is a standard [geometric progression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression). The maximum nodes of a given tree with height `x` and fan-out `f` is therefore the sum of such geometric progression and it shouldn't be too much trouble to figure out the smallest `x`, for which the number of nodes is greater than `n`.

Comment: So after I take the sum of the geometric progression I just solve for x to get the minimum height?  I think the equation I provided above is the sum of the geometric progression you're talking about.

Comment: So I solve for h in this equation: n = (f^(h+t1)-1)/(f-1).  But don't I have to use a floor or ceiling function to make sure I get a whole number for the height?  The nodes don't necessarily each have f children.

Comment: You will need to use ceiling.