# minimum height of a binary tree?

Tags: c++, c, data-structures, tree, binary-tree

I am asking this question after reading the below post:

[How to find minimum possible height of tree?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21763159/how-to-find-minimum-possible-height-of-tree)

Actually I want my algorithm to return 4 if the input given to a binary tree is as follows: 100, 50, 70, 60.

but the below code returns only 1 because it does not distinguish between a leaf[left == NULL && right == NULL] and a node with only one child.

```
int minDepth(TreeNode root)  {
    if (root == null) { 
        return 0;
    }
    return 1 + Math.min(minDepth(root.left), minDepth(root.right));
}
```

No one has explained what should we do if we want the output as 4 instead of 1.

Can anyone please show me the code which returns 4 instead of 1 ?

I think I have chosen the wrong sample values above and people are getting confused about what am I actually looking for !! So, re-framing my questions below:

Assume that any node can have 0,1, or 2 children. Please consider this sample input - 100, 50, 150, 30, 70, 200, 20, 40, 60, 80, 10. Now I want my function to return the height as 3 [100->150->200]. I am calling this branch [100->150->200] as the minimum height of the tree. I may be wrong in the analogy of minimum height BUT all I want is to return 3.

The tree looks like this -

> ```
>                         100
>                       /     \\
>                      /       \\
>                   50          150
>                  /   \           \\
>               30       70         200
>               / \     /  \
>             20  40   60  80
>            /
>           10
> ```

And I need to find out the shortest distance between root node and the leaf node  [100->150->200] =3.

This is my code -

```
struct node
{
    struct node* left;
    int data;
    struct node* right;
};

void add(struct node** root, int data)
{
    if(*root == NULL)
    {
        (*root) = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
        (*root)->left = NULL;
        (*root)->right = NULL;
        (*root)->data = data; 
    }
    else
    {
        if(data < (*root)->data )
            add(&(*root)->left, data);
        else
            add(&(*root)->right, data);
    }

}

void inorder(struct node* root)
{
    if(root == NULL)
        return;
    inorder(root->left);
    cout<<root->data<<" ";
    inorder(root->right);
}

int minDepth(struct node* root)  
{
    if (root == NULL) 
    { 
        return 0;
    }
    return 1 + min(minDepth(root->left), minDepth(root->right));
}

int main()
{
        struct node* root = NULL;
        add(&root, 100);
        add(&root, 50);
        add(&root, 150);
        add(&root, 30);
        add(&root, 70);
        add(&root, 200);
        add(&root, 20);
        add(&root, 40);
        add(&root, 60);
        add(&root, 80);
        add(&root, 10);
        inorder(root);
        cout<<endl;
        int i = minDepth(root);
        cout<<i<<endl; // this should be 3
        getchar();
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: your code finds the length of the shortest branch in a binary tree, not the minimum height of a binary tree.

Comment: @Jatin, maybe you want replace last line with `return 1 + Math.max(...);`, but i'm not shure what you want to get.

Comment: Can you please tell how do we find the minimum height of a binary tree which return 4.

Comment: @  Petr Pervukhin -- No I dont want to find the MAXIMMUM height. So, I am not supposed to replace the last line

Comment: Minimum height of ballanced binary tree is binary logarithm of number of elements in tree. Do you want to calculate height of unballanced tree?

Comment: if you already have a concrete tree, the context of "minimum possible" makes no sense. There is only one possible tree once you've already defined the values. Just find the length of the longest branch and you're done.

Comment: You should try to understand what you are asking for. You have a binary tree of height 4, you want your code to return 4 instead of 1...what does that tell you you really want to do? Max or Min?

Comment: I think I have chosen the wrong sample values.  Assume that any node can have 0,1, or 2 childs. Please consider this sample input - 100, 50, 150, 30, 70, 200, 20, 40, 60, 80, 10.  Now I want my function to return the height as 3 [100->150->200].   I am calling this branch [100->150->200] as the minimum height of the tree.  I may be wrong in the analogy of minimum height BUT all I want is to return 3.

Comment: @Jatin `[100->150->200]` What happens to the other elements? Will these be stored in the tree or not?

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ - All the input elements have been stored. and the output should be 3 because the minimum path from a root node to a leaf node is 3 [100->150->200]

Comment: [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) now, c'mon!! At least make an ASCII drawing, of what your tree actually looks like, after being fed with your input.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ - Its done. Drawn tree diagram. Sorry for troubling you.

Comment: @Jatin Tuned it a bit, if you don't mind.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ -- Sure, please take your own time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63053/discussion-between---and-jatin).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to me that you want to know the size of the tree and not it's height.

So instead of choosing the smallest height of the two subtrees below your root (the minDepth function) you want to sum their sizes.

The following function adds one to the size of each of left and right subtrees if the node is not null (wouldn't really be a node at all and should not be counted).

```
int sizeOfTree(TreeNode root){
    if (root == nulll) {return 0;}
        return 1 + sizeOfTree(root.left) + sizeOfTree(root.right);
}
```

Recursively this will find the number of nodes in your tree (also known as it's size).

EDIT: After the question has been reviewed I think this is what you want:

```
int shortestBranch(TreeNode root){
    if (root == null) {return 0;}
    if (root.left == null && root.right == null){
        return 1;
    } else if (root.left == null) {
        return 1 + shortestBranch(root.right);
    } else if (root.right == null) {
        return 1 + shortestBranch(root.left);
    } else {
        return 1 + Math.min(shortestBranch(root.right), shortestBranch(root.left));
    }
}
```

Comment: NO, I dont want to count the number of nodes present in the tree. I have re-framed my question. Please read it again. So sorry for troubling you :(

Comment: @Jatin Edited. hopefully this is what you wanted.

Comment: @ Ed Smilovici -- YES !!!!  Finally someone understood my complicated explanation correctly :-) Thank you so much

Comment: @RaviMehta It returns the length of the shortest route to a leaf (or the length of the shortest branch).

Answer (score 1):

```
int minDepth( TreeNode root )
{
    if( root == null )
        return 0;
    if( root.left == null && root.right == null )
        return 1;
    int l = minDepth(root.left);
    int r = minDepth(root.right);
    if( l == 0 )
        return r;
    if( r == 0 )
        return l;
    return 1 + Math.min(l,r);
}
```

Comment: NO its not proper. Its not returning 3 for the input sample - 100, 50, 150, 30, 70, 200, 20, 40, 60, 80, 10.

Comment: @Jatin, I fixed this.

Comment: I am sorry to say, but it is still not giving 3 as output [i.e., the shortest distance between the ROOT node and the LEAF node].  [100->150->200]

Comment: Okey, _now_ I understood what you want. =)

Comment: @ Petr Pervukhin - Its returning 1 instead of 3 :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63052/discussion-between-jatin-and-petr-pervukhin).